# Application runs out of memory when started from another application, but not when launched from Visual Studio. Why?

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory-leaks, parallel-processing

I have this console application that handles pretty much data, more specifically it manipulates large Bitmap objects.

When I launch the Console application through Visual Studio, everything works fine. If I launch it from another application through new Process(), the Console application runs into Out of memory exceptions (working with the same data that works well from Visual Studio), and some other GDI+ errors (but I am fairly sure these errors are the result of earlier out of memory exceptions).

I have checked that the Maximum working set of memory is the same when the Console application is run from Visual studio (vshost), and when it is run from another application.

So my question is: Why does this happen??

I can also mention that the Console application is multithreaded.

Comment: Are you disposing of all objects properly that are implementing `IDisposable`?  You should provide a code sample, as it doesn't help us much.  Please review this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm disposing Bitmaps and closing Threads gracefully. Beyond that, I'm mostly dealing with large byte arrays that have short lifespans...

Comment: I would love to provide a code sample if I could, but since there is no defined problem area in the code (Out of memory happens at random stages of the process, depending on the size of the data to be chewed), I have no idea to where begin. And since it works like a charm with vshost, I am unsure if the code is the problem or not at all.

Comment: Find a profiler like ants or scitech and attach it to your program to see what objects are not being disposed that should get you started

Comment: @Terje: large byte arrays with fast allocations can run in to OOM issues if it happens fast enough.  Perhaps you can narrow down the section of your code.  You asked a question "Why does this happen?" yet we have little to no information.  A profiler would also help.

Comment: did you use the same build configuration (debug/release, x86/x64) in both the cases?

Comment: It would probably be easier to tell with short example code that shows the problem

Comment: I'll try the profilers recommended, and see if I can find some hints in the results. There cannot be a short example code that shows the problem. The core part of the code that does image manipulation is about 100,000 lines long, and errors can occur *anywhere* within.

Comment: Note that the GDI Image class(es) throw OOM for all sorts of reasons. So recheck the "the same data". I think you have an invalid (corrupted) bitmap somewhere.

Comment: Do you have control over the hosting application; and if so what happens if you change the code so instead of `new Process(...)` you call the code from the console application directly - it should be possible to treat the console app as a class library?

Comment: @ChrisMoutray yep, I already tried that. That was my initial approach, actually. That still throws OOM errors.